# SFP compatibility with media converter

Tags: networking, fiber, optical-media

Maybe it is a silly question but since I am not so experienced using fiber optics I want to make sure everything is ok before ordering.

I am planning to use this media converter:

https://www.versatek.com/hardened-micro-100base-t-to-100base-sfp-ethernet-media-converter.html

with this 2 BiDi SFPs:

http://shop.fiber24.net/index.php/en/1-250-Gbit-s-10km-SM-Bi-Di-SFP-TX1550nm-RX-1310nm/c-SFP-SM-BIDI/a-FOSF-LI-F433S17415-D?sidE70A6A1096464AEFB3364F28B60C3BC6=vrtuvv039l6k78rqgi15034bl4
the other is the one recommended in the link before FOSF-LI-F433I17431-D ( i cannot post more than 2 links)
The media converter is for 100M speed and the SPF can go up to 1.25G (as far as I know they can adapt between 100M-1.25G)

I am asking because I saw some kind of issues that can occur due to compatibility between manufacturers but I don't know if it is between SFPs only or also media converters. So if I use this setup, would that be ok? I mean, would the media converter work fine with those SFPs?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally bought the components, tried them and they worked

Answer (score 0):

You bought your optical transceivers and media converters at different places, it is risky for an inexperienced stuff to do that as there might be compatibility issues. For me, if you want to save cost, find a reliable OEM vendor is Ok, but you'd better inquiry well to ensure that there would be no problem. Good Luck